# Eval script for server side control's ID property?

Tags: asp.net, eval

Using the following Eval script for setting ID property causes error.
Error message: the server tag is not well formed.

```
 <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="<%# Eval("RENTER_ID") %>" Visible="false">
```

Even replacing "" with '' of ID property generates error.
While using '', its error message

"The ID property of a control can only be set using the ID attribute in the tag and a simple value. Example: `<asp:Button runat="server" id="Button1" />`"

Any ideas to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it.

Why do you need to? If it's so you can reference it at some point, you can access the client-side id via the property [ClientID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx).

Example, as requested:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repFoo">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlFoo">
            <input type = "button"
                onclick = "alert('<%# Container.FindControl("pnlFoo").ClientID %>');"
                value   = "click to get id for <%# Container.ItemIndex %>" />
        </asp:Panel>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: That panel is to be rendered for each item in GridView to be later expanded/collapsed.

Comment: If you are doing the same but for div element, it works properly.
<div id="<%# Eval("CustomerID") %>" style="display: none; position: relative">

Comment: Yes, that's because it's not a server control. Effectively you are trying to `name a variable` at run time; and that's just not possible. To get a unique ID, for expanding/collapsing, use the `ClientID`, like I suggest. (Something like: <script>alert("<%# FooControl.ClientID %>");).

Comment: Please explain using ClientID more? How to use it to retrieve div of that item?

Comment: Works properly, thanks, but what in case if I need to get that Panel ID for selected item in code behind?

Comment: What do you mean? You do the same thing: Determine the row, search for it using the ID `pnlFool` and `FindControl`?

Comment: Determine row is done using SelectedIndex for GridView.
I need to use that index to find panel in code behind?
Something like this :  ((Panel)gvCustomers.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("pnlDocuments")).Visible = true;

If you are going to run this, panel reference is null as nothing found? So, I just asking how to use ClientID for panel to set its properities in code behind.

Comment: And where are you executing that code? In OnDataBound? That's where I would do it; and in that case you don't use the `ClientID`, you just use what you write in the "ID" (i.e. 'pnlDocuments'). Take some time to work up a small example of this, and test it yourself. I leave it with you.

Answer (score 1):

As Silky said, you can't do this. The attributes can't be dynamic in none code behind. One solution is to subclass the Panel:

```
public class MyPanel : Panel
{
    public override string ID
    {
        get
        {
            return "get from my datasource";
        }
        set
        {
            // noop
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: return "get from my datasource"; means?

Comment: Whatever your 'RENTER_ID' is from. You'd have to give your Panel a property to grab this from.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <div runat="server" id='<%# Eval("IsVisible") %>' visible="false"> </div>
```

Try this - It will not popup any messages if you do formatting, but it will show Design time error.

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID='<%# Eval("RENTER_ID") %>' Visible="false">
```

Comment: This also raises an error.
Error: The ID property of a control can only be set using the ID attribute in the tag and a simple value. Example: <asp:Button runat="server" id="Button1" />and

Comment: Yes, I think it is only for server controls. But you can try like 
<div runat="server" id='<%# Eval("IsVisible") %>' visible="false"></div>, atleast it is not displaying design time errors.

Comment: <div runat="server" id='<%# Eval("IsVisible") %>' visible="false"> </div>

this also won't work. runat="server" generates the same error for panel.

Comment: @Anuraj - how did you get over 8,000 reputation points with a poorly researched answer as this? I am dumbfounded

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use a panel?  Could you just use html?

```
<div id="<%# Eval("RENTER_ID") %>" style="display:none"></div>
```

Comment: Either asp:panel or div; its visible property should be set server side.
So, we need that id? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

asp.net controls' ID doesn't support the binding. Try to use HTML controls to work around.

Answer (score 0):

It almost always when asp.net fails , comes Jquery into the field to set the situation up ;) . you can do this trick for example :

In HTML:

```
<div>
<input type="file" id="whatever" class="uploader" runat="server" />
<span id="<%#Eval("ID")%>'"></span>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
    $('.uploader').on('change', function () {
        var id = $(this).next('span').attr('id');
     });
```