# Customizing the ID value for asp:GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

In my aspx page, I have the following code to generate a asp:Table

**abc.aspx**

```
<asp:Table id = "_tableTest" runat="server"></asp:Table>
```

When I render it on the page , I need the id to be prepend with a text , for example "Address"

```
<table id="Address_tableTest" > </table>
```

How can I customize the ID generation? I couldnt find relevant documentation.

Comment: Why not simply `ID="Address_tableTest"`? And maybe set the ClientIDMode to static.

Comment: I am not suppose to change the markup as the prefix  value can be read from 3rd party, it has to be <asp:Table id = "_tableTest"....   . What other options do we have to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean? If some 3rd party needs the table name, then you can't change it. I mean, either you type in Address_tableTest as the ID, or you don't. The "id" is NOT generated for you, YOU the developer type it into the markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean? If some 3rd party needs the table name, then you can't change it. I mean, either you type in Address_tableTest as the ID, or you don't.

The "id" is NOT generated for you, YOU the developer type it into the markup

You can change the "id" in the forms pre-render event.

In fact, you can even change it in the page on-load event.

```
            this.GridView1.ID = "abc";
```

or

```
 GridView1.ID = "Address_" + GridView1.ID.ToString();
```

The "id" in markup will now thus render and use "abc".

However, code behind will continue to use "this.GridView1" to reference the control.

Answer (score 0):

You can append it.

```
<asp:Table id = '<%# Eval("Id") + "_TableName" %>' runat="server"></asp:Table>
```

[what is the use of Eval() in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793274/what-is-the-use-of-eval-in-asp-net)

Yes @VDWWD is correct Id can not be set dynamically

> The ID property of a control can only be set using the ID attribute in the tag and a simple value. Error Generated by webforms when I tried to set it dynamically.

It is explained here in this post [Eval script for server side control's ID property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859206/eval-script-for-server-side-controls-id-property)

Comment: This does not work. You cannot set an id of an asp:control like that.